# Binded command in .NET Maui not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I have a small .net maiu mobile app which I am developing using the MVVM patter.
I have a basic xaml view which beside other small UI elements has this button:

```
<Button
x:Name="Mbl_Btn"
Margin="0,15,0,0"
WidthRequest="150"
BorderColor="#F65900"
FontSize="Medium"
FontFamily="MontserratMedium"
VerticalOptions="Center"
HorizontalOptions="Center"
Text="Send"
Command="{Binding My_Command_Name}"
BackgroundColor="#F65900">
```

The Viewmodel of this view is already binded in the code behind.
Inside the viewmodel I have an implementation of a function declared this way:

```
 public async Task<bool> My_Func(List<Blocks> Blocks){ ... }
 
 public ICommand My_Command_Name{  get; set; }
```

The parameter that My_Func takes in is declared this way

```
private List<Boxes> _boxes;
public List<Boxes> Boxes
{
  get { return _boxes; }
  set
   {
      if(_boxes!= value)
        {
          _boxes= value;
          OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Boxes));
      }
   }
```

}

There is also other code but for this question I assume it is not that relevant,
in the constructor of the viewmodel I have this:

```
public MyViewmodel(){ 
  /* code .... */
  else {
      My_Command_Name = new Command<List<Boxes>>(async (Boxes) => await 
       My_Func(Boxes)):
   }
  /* code ... */
}
```

The problem is that the command never gets executed. Any clues?

Comment: your command method requires an argument, but you have not defined a value for `CommandParameter`

Comment: Can you provide some information about what you want to do by using the command. It is easy to bind the command to the button and it may not be the issue caused by the binding.